# Syntax error for insert query alias in Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO emailevents (shopid, userid, emailid, campaignid, variationid, type, createdon) 
VALUES ($1,                 
(SELECT id FROM users WHERE mongoid=$2), 
(SELECT id FROM emails WHERE mongoid=$3), 
(SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4) AS cid, 
(SELECT id FROM campaignvariations WHERE templateid=(SELECT id FROM templates WHERE mongoid=$5) AND campaignid=cid), 
$6, 
to_timestamp($7))
```

and I'm getting this error:`Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"`

I've tried putting cid inside the bracket, without success.

How should I use the alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change to `select` instead of `values` as below

```
INSERT INTO emailevents (shopid, userid, emailid, campaignid, variationid, type, createdon)      
select $1,                 
       (SELECT id FROM users WHERE mongoid=$2), 
       (SELECT id FROM emails WHERE mongoid=$3), 
       (SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4) AS cid, 
       (SELECT id FROM campaignvariations WHERE templateid=(SELECT id FROM templates WHERE mongoid=$5) AND campaignid=(SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4)), 
       $6, 
       to_timestamp($7)
```

I think you should replace `cit` with `(SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4)` for `variationid` column

Answer (score 1):

One fix is to change the `values` to a `select`:

```
INSERT INTO emailevents (shopid, userid, emailid, campaignid, variationid, type, createdon) 
    select $1,                 
           (SELECT id FROM users WHERE mongoid=$2), 
           (SELECT id FROM emails WHERE mongoid=$3), 
           (SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4) AS cid, 
           (SELECT id FROM campaignvariations WHERE templateid=(SELECT id FROM templates WHERE mongoid=$5) AND campaignid=cid), 
            $6, 
            to_timestamp($7);
```

I prefer using `insert . . . select` rather than `insert . . . values` in general.

You might be able to just remove the `as cid` if Postgres supports subqueries in the `values` statement.

EDIT:

The above fixes the `as` problem, but not the overall problem.  Let's use `select` and move most of the subqueries to the `from` clause:

```
INSERT INTO emailevents (shopid, userid, emailid, campaignid, variationid, type, createdon) 
    select const.shopid,  u.id, e.id, c.id                
           (SELECT id
            FROM campaignvariations
            WHERE templateid=(SELECT id FROM templates WHERE mongoid=$5) AND campaignid=c.id
           ), 
           const.type, 
           const.createdon
    from (select $1 as shopid, $6 as type, to_timestamp($7) as createdon) const left outer join
         (SELECT id FROM users WHERE mongoid=$2) u cross join
         (SELECT id FROM emails WHERE mongoid=$3) e cross join
         (SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE mongoid=$4) c;
```

Comment: but I'm using cid for the next subquery, that's why I need it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use variables and you want to use `cid` in the query, you can precalculate it with cte:

```
with cte_cid as (
    select (select id from campaigns where mongoid=$4) as cid -- need 2 selects in case you don't have record for mongoid=$4
)
insert into emailevents (shopid, userid, emailid, campaignid, variationid, type, createdon)      
select $1 as shopid,              
   (select t.id from users as t where t.mongoid=$2), 
   (select t.id from emails as t where t.mongoid=$3), 
   cid,
   (select t.id from campaignvariations as t where t.templateid=(select tt.id from templates as tt where tt.mongoid=$5) and t.campaignid=c.cid), 
$6,
   to_timestamp($7)
from cte_cid as c
```